# NavigationView title doesn't appear when the views are in TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview

I have two Views and each of them contains NavigationView with title. I have created a TabBar View which also has a NavigationView on it.

```
struct TabbarView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
    TabView {
        MainContentView()
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Text("Main")
                }
        }.tag(0)

        SearchContentView()
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Text("Search")
                }
        }.tag(1)
    }
    }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

}

I have tried hiding the navigationBar for this view but that doesn't work. Only the navigation bar of this view appears.

This is `MainContentView()`

```
struct MainContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Text("Some Content View")
        }
    .navigationBarTitle("Travel")
}
```

}

Any idea how to go about this. Thanks!

Update:
Basically when I tap on a **Log In** Button, I am passing TabBarView() through NavigationLink.

```
   NavigationLink(destination: TabbarView()) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Log In")
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 40, height: 40)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }.padding(.bottom, 40)
```

In doing that, it shows the TabbarView() with child views this is what I see:
The space above "Travel" (navigationBarTitle of the childView) is the navigationBar of the tabbar since I am pushing it into navigationStack.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first thing to point out here is that all of the navigation bar modifiers you have in your code should be modifiers on a view inside of the `NavigationView`, not modifiers on `NavigationView` itself. From the documentation for `.navigationBarTitle`, for example:

> This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible within a NavigationView.

Also, there is no need to have a `NavigationView` wrapping your `TabView` and then another inside your `MainContentView`. This will only lead to nested navigation bars, and you definitely don't want that. Instead, just use one `NavigationView`. I would also suggest that you not put the `NavigationView` inside the `MainContentView` body.

I've refactored your code to show what I'm talking about, although I wasn't sure where you were trying to use `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden` and `.navigationBarHidden`, so I omitted them. Just keep in mind that they function just like `.navigationBarTitle` - you need to use them as modifiers on a view inside `NavigationView`, not on `NavigationView` itself.

```swift
struct TabBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                MainContentView()
            }
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Main")
                }

            SearchContentView()
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Search")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MainContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Some Content View")
            .navigationBarTitle("Travel")
    }
}
```

As you might notice, I also removed the `VStack` from `.tabItem`. You can put both `Text` and `Image` inside `.tabItem` without the need for a `VStack`, and if I'm not mistaken, `.tabItem` ignores anything that is not `Text` or `Image` anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detail answer and explaining the concept. I will implement it tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: I implemented the above code and it works fine. However, the child views inside tabView still appears in middle of the screen. As in the 'Travel' title appears few inches below where it actually should be. It's as if the tabbar has a navigation bar as well.

Comment: @OsamaNaeem I don't have that same issue. Can you add a picture of the canvas to your question so I can see what you're referring to?

Comment: Hey, I just updated the question. I guess it seems to be a tab bar being pushed into the navigationStack.

Comment: In a navigation stack, there should only be one `NavigationView`. Otherwise you’ll end up with nested navigation bars like you have there. You also should not be pushing a tab bar onto the navigation stack - that’s not how tab bars were designed to be used. If you need to push these views onto the navigation stack, then you should remove the tab bar and find another way to layout your view hierarchy. Maybe search could be a bar button item that presents a modal view - just so long as you only have one navigation view per navigation stack and one tab bar switching between different view stacks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If anyone wants the navigation bar to encroach beneath the top safe area as normal, you need to add `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` to the `TabView` itself

Comment: if I nest NavigationView inside a TabView, I see the TabView bottom bar on every childview I push on my navigation view. is there any way to hide that ?

Comment: This is not a good answer because you are not able to hide tab view in child views.... purpose is defeated

Comment: @Andre Hiding the tab bar in child views doesn’t have anything to do with this question. Also, hiding the tab bar is done using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` which is not available in SwiftUI at the moment as far as I know. Nesting a `TabView` inside a `NavigationView` is NOT the way to allow for hiding of the tab bar.

Comment: @graycampbell I'm just now learning that fact. Seems that the documentation for this is not too great. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

If you need Login/SignUp View before tabview do not use NavigationView to wrap it. In the Login/Sign up view

```
@EnvironmentObject var authService:AuthService

var body: some View{
    ZStack{
        if(!authService.isSignedIn){
            Button(action: {
                self.authService.signIn()
            }) {
                Text("Login")
            }
        }
        else{
            TabBarView()
        }
    }
}
```

In the subviews you can control the *isSignedIn* variable with `@EnvironmentObject` and change that value when Signed Out
This is an example of the `TabBarView()` used before:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationView{
            FirstView()
        }
        .tabItem {
            VStack{
                Image("first")
                Text("First")
            }
        }
        NavigationView{
            SecondView()
        }
        .tabItem {
            VStack{
                Image("second")
                Text("Second")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is could be one of the tabviews:

```
@EnvironmentObject var authService:AuthService

var body: some View {
    TextView("Hello World")
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: LogOutButton(logOutFunction: authService.signOut))
}
```

Comment: This is ok, but you don't get an animation effect when authService.isSignedIn is true. It will just blink into the TabView. Not cute.

Comment: is there a better way to navigate from Login to TabView?

Answer (score 0):

This works too in iOS 13:

```
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                FirstTabbarView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .navigationBarTitle("NavBar title Tabbar1", displayMode: .inline)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("Tab bar 1")
            }
            
            NavigationView {
                SecondTabbarView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .navigationBarTitle("Navbar title Tabbar 2", displayMode: .inline)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                Text("Tab bar 2")
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want dynamic navigation title you can do something like this

```
struct ContentView: App {
@State var selection = 1

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                GridView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Study", systemImage: "book")
                            .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                    }
                    .tag(1)
                
                StudyView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Test", systemImage: "graduationcap")
                    }
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .navigationTitle(selection == 1 ? "Study a Language" : "Take a Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you're getting a warning like this **Trying to pop to a missing destination - SwiftUI/NavigationBridge_PhoneTV.swift:213**
you can probably follow this blog
https://computerlounge.it/swifui-trying-to-pop-to-missing-destination/