# SwiftUI TabView in NavigationView hierarchical stack has extra space at the top of the screen

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, tabview

I have a flow of user registration. Where Welcome screen wrapped in NavigationView and then after several screens NavigationLink opens TabView. As I understand, as a result, TabView is in this navigation stack and has an extra space at the top of the screen. How to avoid this situation?
I've tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57332701/9325884
But it works only if you have one aka Login screen. So, I'm looking for a solution how to switch between two Navigation stacks. TIA

Comment: You might find helpful approach proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59560140/12299030) topic, which also considered possibilities to make friends NavigationView with TabView

Comment: This could be the right approach for you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104813/change-the-root-view-of-uihostingcontroller-in-swiftui/58105259#58105259

Comment: @LuLuGaGa, thank you! That way is a good one when registration is already finished. I'm in the process of it. When registration is finished and the next screen should start from TabView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this article - [link here](https://www.blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-environmentobject)
 and used @EnvironmentObject to manage what screen to show for my user depending on state